# IntelliJ .iml files keep getting wrong path

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a nested maven project. When I initially import, everything works great. If I look at the content of the *.iml file it contains:

```
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/generated-sources/xjc" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
</content>
```

Some time later, especially after I've changed a pom.xml file, I go to run some tests, but they do not run as IntelliJ can't find my source code. Back to the iml file, I see things have changed :

```
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../myProject/featureA/core">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../myProject/featureA/core/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../myProject/featureA/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../myProject/featureA/core/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../myProject/featureA/core/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../myProject/featureA/core/target/generated-sources/xjc" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../myProject/featureA/core/target" />
</content>
```

This is an example in one of the nested projects, but it is true at all levels, including the top level. This is weird, and it is the wrong path (it would actually be the right path if I take out one of the `../`'s)

Similarily, in my root-level .idea\modules.xml file, all of the paths have an extra `../` in them.

So far the only workaround is to correct all the paths in modules.xml, remove all the *.iml files and reimport, but this is a pain. Any idea how I can prevent this?

Comment: What is your project structure? Do you have only pom.xml or other build systems configured? One module (represented by .iml file) is configured per one pom.xml file. And IDE takes the module structure information from pom.xml in case of the Maven(Gradle/SBT) projects on re-import. You can file a [request](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731) with the sample project to check it's structure and configuration of it in IDE.

Comment: We have Gradle configuration (because we are moving there soon) but are not using it. I chose to import as maven and have IntelliJ skip the Gradle stuff when it asked. Our structure is pretty deeply nested, with some modules imported as Maven externals. Perhaps the complicated maven structure is causing this? I've never had these problems with Eclipse. I'll try again when we move to Gradle, hopefully better luck then.